# Add TestDevice to admob Interstitial Ad (no Banner Ads)

Tags: android, admob

I know for Banner Ads you do it this way

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);               
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("4CCC00EF4EA205A6FE82E1AEB26B0839")
            .build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

How to add a testDevice while using only Interstitial Ads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same way. You add test device to the `AdRequest` object.

Refer official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#adding_interstitial_ads_to_an_activity)

Extract from documentation:

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
              .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: My Bad! That thing, haha! Sorry!